# Is it possible to move / merge messages between RabbitMQ queues?

Tags: python, queue, rabbitmq, amqp, pika

I'm looking to know is it possible to move / merge messages from one queue to another.
For example:

`main-queue` contains messages `['cat-1','cat-2','cat-3','cat-4','dog-1','dog-2','cat-5']`

`dog-queue` contains messages `['dog-1, dog-2, dog-3, dog-4]`

So the question is, (assuming both queues are on the same cluster, vhost)  it possible to move messages from `dog-queue` to `main-queue` using `rabbitmqctl` ?

So at the end I'm looking to get something like:

## Ideally:

`main-queue` : `['cat-1','cat-2','cat-3','cat-4','dog-1','dog-2','cat-5', dog-3, dog-4]`

## But this is ok too:

`main-queue` : `['cat-1','cat-2','cat-3','cat-4','dog-1','dog-2','cat-5', 'dog-1, dog-2, dog-3, dog-4]`

Comment: I think you might need to look in to topic exchanges

Answer (score 22, accepted):

What you are/were looking for is the 'shovel' plugin. The shovel plugin comes built into the core but you have to explicitly enable it. It's really easy to use as it does everything for you (no manually consuming/republishing to another queue).

Enable shovel plugin via cli:

```
sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_shovel
```

If you manage RabbitMQ via GUI, install the shovel mgmt plugin too:

```
sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_shovel_management
```

Login to the GUI and you will see Shovel Management under the Admin section. You can create shovels to move messages from any queue to another queue, even remotely hosted queues. You can delete the shovel when it's finished, or leave it there and it'll continually move the messages as they come in.

---

If you manage RabbitMQ via CLI, you can execute shovel directly from rabbitmqctl:

```
sudo rabbitmqctl set_parameter shovel cats-and-dogs \
'{"src-uri": "amqp://user:pass@host/vhost", "src-queue": "dog-queue", \
"dest-uri": "amqp://user:pass@host/vhost", "dest-queue": "main-queue"}'
```

---

Official plugin docs:

Shovel Plugin - https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html
Creating Shovels - https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel-dynamic.html

Comment: That's right. I didn't noted that it possible via shovels. Thanks for providing correct answer and sorry for incorrect answer.

Comment: Note, you don't have to enable shovel plugin on every machine, while you can set it up even on some remote machine and have both source and destination also remote servers.

Comment: @rocksfrow, installed `rabbitmq_management` on all nodes is not a must.

Comment: @zaq178miami I updated my answer and removed the note about installing the management plugin on every node, although I still personally think you should the plugin on all of your nodes -- otherwise you'll potentially run into management issues after a node failure.

Comment: @rocksfrow, or any one here, what will be the output of this??

Comment: I tried this, but it is not showing any success/failure message

Comment: For future reference. I am using the plugin described by @rocksfrow I had a issue where my "Move" function with the admin GUI didn't work then I deleted the temporary shovel that was created and tried again then on the second attempt it moved the items.