# Moving messages between queues rabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, message, messaging, amqp

I am looking to be able to move messages between queues (manually) in Rabbit.

For example:

```
first-queue has messages ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
second-queue has messages ['x','y']
```

I want to be able to move for example message 'a' to second-queue from first-queue. This can be a manual operation. Both queues are on the same broker, and I do not want to send them through any exchange. Is there anyway to do this? I have been playing with rabbitmqctl but can't seem to get it to work. I am open to any other tools that would allow me to accomplish this. Eventually I am hoping to have some sort of message selector (for example move all messages with some header field = X from first-queue to second-queue).

I am still new to rabbitmq and amqp but have been unable to find documentation on how to do this (if it is even possible).

Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

@Dax - I just answered this same question here: [Is it possible to move / merge messages between RabbitMQ queues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075116/is-it-possible-to-move-merge-messages-between-rabbitmq-queues/26814659#26814659)

I have a long description there. To avoid duplicate content I don't want to copy/paste.

It sounds like what you are looking for is the rabbitmq shovel plugin.

It is built into the core, simply enable it:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_shovel
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_shovel_management
```

From the Admin section in the GUI you'll find an easy interface to create shovels.

See other post for me deets!

Comment: I see the Move Messages option in the queues as an administrator, but users are not seeing this option.  How do we give them access to this option with queues they and config, write, and read?

Answer (score 8):

The fact that it's not documented is because it's far away from messaging model.

It's easy to send a message to a specific queue - see [tutorial #1](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html) for example - but the only way to read messages is to *consume* them, in the order the broker send to the clients.

It's not allowed to *select* messages from a queue as you can do with SQL.

What you can do is to let a client (or eventually, a plugin, but this is an advanced topic) *consume* messages from a queue, and based on some rule you re-*publish* them to a subsequent queue or to another one.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple java code to move everything from one queue to another:

```
public void moveMessages(
            final String sourceQueueName,
            final String targetQueueName,
            final String rabbitmqHost,
            final String rabbitmqUsername,
            final String rabbitmqPassword,
            final String rabbitmqVirtualHost
) throws IOException {

        // Initialize the consuming and publishing channel
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost(rabbitmqHost);
        factory.setUsername(rabbitmqUsername);
        factory.setPassword(rabbitmqPassword);
        factory.setVirtualHost(rabbitmqVirtualHost);
        Connection connection = factory.newConnection();

        Channel consumingChannel = connection.createChannel();
        Channel publishingChannel = connection.createChannel();


        while (true) {
            // Get the first message in the queue (auto ack = false)
            GetResponse response = consumingChannel.basicGet(sourceQueueName, false);

            if (response == null) {
                return;
            }

            BasicProperties properties = response.getProps();

            // Publish the message to the origin queue
            publishingChannel.txSelect();
            publishingChannel.basicPublish("", targetQueueName, (AMQP.BasicProperties) properties, response.getBody());
            publishingChannel.txCommit();

            // Acknowledge the message in the dead letter queue
            consumingChannel.basicAck(response.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a shovel using this curl  :

```
curl 
-u  "user:password" 
-vvv 'http://localhost:15672/api/parameters/shovel/%2Foms/Move%20from%20sourceQueue' 
-X PUT 
-H 'content-type: application/json' 
--data-binary '
{
    "component": "shovel",
    "vhost": "/vhost",
    "name": "Move from sourceQueue",
    "value": {
        "src-uri": "amqp:///%2Fvhost",
        "src-queue": "sourceQueue",
        "src-protocol": "amqp091",
        "src-prefetch-count": 1000,
        "src-delete-after": "queue-length",
        "dest-protocol": "amqp091",
        "dest-uri": "amqp:///%2Fvhost",
        "dest-add-forward-headers": false,
        "ack-mode": "on-confirm",
        "dest-queue": "destQueue"
    }
}
' --compressed
```