# How to migrate messages from an exclusive queue?

Tags: rabbitmq

I want to migrate messages on an existing exclusive queue to another queue for preservation, because it's misconfigured and its consumer need to be updated.

How can I migrate those messages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving messages between queues rabbitMQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645517/moving-messages-between-queues-rabbitmq)

Comment: You can use `shovel` to move messages between queues. https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html

Comment: @bumblebee It's not possible with an exclusive queue, because it will reject any additional connection.