# Rabbitmq. Move part of messages from one queue to another

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-shovel

I have two queues

For example:

```
A = ['foo', 'abo', 'aboba', 'bar'];
B = [];
```

I'd like to move only `'aboba', 'bar'` from queue *A* to *B*. It doesn't matter which side of *A* to cut.

I know about **rabbitmq shovel**, but I don't found tools for my case in this plugin.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving messages between queues rabbitMQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645517/moving-messages-between-queues-rabbitmq)  and  [Is it possible to move / merge messages between RabbitMQ queues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075116/is-it-possible-to-move-merge-messages-between-rabbitmq-queues/26814659#26814659)

Comment: @Luuk, Unfortunately no. I have seen these questions. I only need to transfer a few messages. Not all messages from the queue *A*

Comment: And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22646229/724039) might solve your problem, but I cannot oversee if that creates another problem   (this = reading all messages from the queue, and re-post them to the correct queue)

Comment: @Luuk, yes. This solution will create another problem.

Comment: OK, then I do not know if it is possible,

Answer (score 0):

In your example you could set a `max-length`-policy to `2` and then use a shovel to move the remaining messages.

This is not a general solution as you might not know at which depth in the queue you are to create the cut.